# IE11 querySelector() is null but querySelectorAll() is not

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to fix a bug specific to IE11/Windows 7, where I am inside an iframe and `iframeEl.querySelector('#description');` is returning `null`.

However, if I change to `iframeEl.querySelectorAll('#description');` it returns nodeList.

What is difference with this DOM lookup?
[image]

Also, why would `getElementById` not be available?

[image]

It related to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` in anyway?

Comment: To your second question: `getElementById` only exists on `document`.

Comment: try `document.querySelector('#description')` OR replace with `document.getElementById('description')`

Comment: Can you run this snippet? It’s a sort of check against invisible characters, delayed evaluation, and other weirdness. `(function (e) { var selector = '#description'; return [e.querySelector(selector) === null, e.querySelectorAll(selector).length]; })(formView)`

Comment: Did you check to see if the nodeList contains any nodes?  querySelectorAll will always return a nodelist.  It may be empty, but it's still a nodelist.

Comment: does nodeList contains any nodes?  yes!  the right one :)

Comment: this is inside an iframe, so cannot use `document`, but a ref to a node in an iframe that does the lookup

Comment: I missed the nodelist at the bottom, sorry.

Comment: Is the src of the iframe in the same domain as the page?  If not, you're running up against XSS protections.  (though querySelectorAll shouldn't work either in that case)

Comment: @Ry- that returned `[true, 1]`

Comment: @PhilLucks: That’s weird. Do `Function.prototype.toString.call(formView.querySelector)` and `Function.prototype.toString.call(formView.querySelectorAll)` return the same thing?

Comment: @Ry- it appears to be the same "thing", as both are `[native code]`

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem on my side, if I use querySelectorAll() method, the return array is empty, if I use querySelector() method, the result is null.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the following code to get an element from within an iframe (it works well on my side).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGetvalue").click(function () {

                var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");
                var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("txtname").value;

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe  id="iframeId" src="HtmlPage19.html" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
    <input id="btnGetvalue" type="button" value="GetValue" />
</body>
```